# Dialog wait for download and thread issuse

Tags: multithreading, dialog, codenameone, event-dispatch-thread

I'm trying to display a dialog when user attempts to download something, but when the dialog is dismissed, the app redirects back to an earlier form page.  The download works but the next form does not; just keeps displaying a 'Loading' dialog and returning to the previous form.

The looping form was commented out of the code below..

```
    ConnectionRequest request = new ConnectionRequest();

//        InfiniteProgress ip = new InfiniteProgress();
//        Dialog dlg = ip.showInifiniteBlocking();
//        request.setDisposeOnCompletion(dlg);
          Hashtable param_data_url = new Hashtable();
          param_data_url.put("index", 0);
          param_data_url.put("rango", 10);
          param_data_url.put("ciudad_id", Constants.CodigoCiudadActual);

          String urlBusqueda = Constants.URL_SERVICIO_SHOW_PRODUCTOS_ADOM_MOVIL;
          String url_conexion = Constants.getUrlServicio(Constants.URL_SERVIDOR_APLICACION, Constants.URL_APLICACION, urlBusqueda, param_data_url);

          request.setUrl(url_conexion);

                    request.addResponseListener(new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
NetworkEvent netEvt = (NetworkEvent) evt;
                            byte[] dataArray = (byte[]) netEvt.getMetaData();

                            try {
                                JSONParser p = new JSONParser();
                                InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(dataArray);
                                Hashtable h = p.parse(new InputStreamReader(is));

                                Enumeration enumCate = h.elements();

                                productoDelegado proDel = new productoDelegado();

                                imagenDelegado imaDel = new imagenDelegado();

                                while (enumCate.hasMoreElements()) {
                                    Hashtable aux = (Hashtable) enumCate.nextElement();
                                    Enumeration enumCate2 = aux.elements();
                                    while (enumCate2.hasMoreElements()) {
                                        Hashtable aux2 = (Hashtable) enumCate2.nextElement();
                                        Enumeration enumCate3 = aux2.elements();
                                        String[] param = new String[8];
                                        param[0] = ((Hashtable) aux2.get("DomPro")).get("producto_id").toString();
                                        param[1] = ((Hashtable) aux2.get("Producto")).get("nombre").toString();
                                        param[2] = ((Hashtable) aux2.get("Producto")).get("precio").toString();
                                        param[3] = ((Hashtable) aux2.get("Producto")).get("tienda_id").toString();
                                        param[4] = ((Hashtable) aux2.get("Producto")).get("calificacion").toString();
                                        param[5] = ((Hashtable) aux2.get("Imagen")).get("id").toString();
                                        param[6] = ((Hashtable) aux2.get("Producto")).get("tipo").toString();
                                        param[7] = "1";

                                        try {
                                            Imagen ima = new Imagen();
                                            ima.setId(param[5]);
                                            Producto prod = new Producto(param[0], param[1], "", param[2], "", param[4], param[3], ima, "", 0, 0, null, param[6], param[7]);

                                            if (proDel.existProducto(Integer.valueOf(param[0]))) {
                                                proDel.createProducto(prod);
                                            }

                                        } catch (Exception ex) {

                                            System.out.println("Error insertanto producto");

                                        }

                                        String[] paramIma = new String[3];
                                        paramIma[0] = ((Hashtable) aux2.get("Imagen")).get("id").toString();
                                        System.out.println(paramIma[0]);
                                        paramIma[1] = ((Hashtable) aux2.get("Imagen")).get("url").toString();
                                        System.out.println(paramIma[1]);

                                        if(!((Hashtable) aux2.get("Imagen")).get("name").toString().equalsIgnoreCase("default.jpg")){
                                            Vector nombre = split(((Hashtable) aux2.get("Imagen")).get("name").toString(), ".");   
                                        paramIma[2] = nombre.elementAt(0).toString() + ".thumb." + nombre.elementAt(1).toString();
                                        }else{
                                        paramIma[2]=((Hashtable) aux2.get("Imagen")).get("name").toString();

                                        }

                                        Imagen ima = new Imagen(paramIma[0], paramIma[1], paramIma[2]);

                                        try {
                                            if (imaDel.existImagen(Integer.valueOf(ima.getId()))) {
                                                imaDel.createImagen(ima);
                                            }
                                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                                            System.out.println("Error insertanto producto");
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                //empieza a renderizar la lista

                                Vector vect = proDel.listProdDesta();
createContainer(getResourceFilePath(), "AvatarContProdDestacado");
                                Enumeration enumPro = vect.elements();
                                Vector VectorDatos = new Vector();
                                int i = 0;

                                while (enumPro.hasMoreElements()) {
                                    Producto pro = (Producto) enumPro.nextElement();
                                    Imagen imagenPro = imaDel.getImagen(Integer.valueOf(pro.getIcono_producto().getId()));
                                    Hashtable dato = new Hashtable();
                                    System.out.println(pro.getId());
                                    dato.put("UrlImagen", Constants.URL_SERVIDOR_APLICACION + Constants.URL_APLICACION + imagenPro.getUrl() + imagenPro.getName());
                                    dato.put("Producto_id", pro.getId());
                                    dato.put("Label2", pro.getNombre());
                                    dato.put("Label", pro.getPrecio());
                                    cmp2.addItem(dato);

                                                                          " timeout:"+is.getTimeout()
ImageDownloadService(dato.get("UrlImagen").toString(), cmp2, i, "avatar");
cmp2, i, "avatar", dato.get("Producto_id").toString(), new Dimension(100, 100), ImageDownloadService.PRIORITY_CRITICAL);

//            NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(ids);
                                        System.err.println(dato.get("UrlImagen"));
                                        ImageDownloadService ids = new ImageDownloadService(dato.get("UrlImagen").toString(), cmp2, i, "avatar");
//                                        ids.setPriority(ImageDownloadService.PRIORITY_CRITICAL);

                                        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(ids);
                                    } catch (Exception ex) {

           System.out.println("Error en la descarga de imagen ImageDownloadService.createImageToStorage");

                                    }
                                    i++;
                                }

                              cmp2.repaint();
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                System.err.println("error");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(request);
                }
            });

        }
return true;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you may have some syntax errors

Comment: should be for the copy and paste, but it works just i need the dialog when the app is downloading content .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indentation and block of code makes this almost impossible to read and you cut off the top of the call so its impossible to really know. However, since you return from some sort of method and return a value I'm assuming your logic incorrectly expects synchronous behavior where `addToQueue` is asynchronous.

Try changing `addToQueue` into `addToQueueAndWait`.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. im still having this error-> http://youtu.be/H1g1PnN8wS8 , your change, doesnt work. i upload a file with all the code https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0IrDoDc8jE4bF9qWmppeFBTU00/edit?usp=sharing  thanks

Comment: You are violating the EDT, its hard to tell what you are doing from this and unfortunately I don't have the time to go into your drive and inspect the files (I deal with hundreds of support cases per day). I suggest you run in the debugger and try to narrow down the code to the specific thing that fails so you can either understand the problem or at least clearly explain it.

Comment: thank, is just one file, contains the initList making the dowload , i uploaded because is more easy for understand. i'm still having the error . edt violation in Dialog dlg = ip.showInifiniteBlocking(); the conection request are in 

if (Display.getInstance().isEdt()) {
            Display.getInstance().scheduleBackgroundTask(new Runnable() {
                public void run() { code of my question}});}

Comment: A background task isn't on the EDT.

Comment: :o thanks i just put out the connection request of edt and finally works. thank you so much. i'm trying to make multi downloads  with just one dialog "loading" , but for now thank you, so much. :)